# Cairo dock for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, dock, cairo

I was using Ubuntu 11.10 with cairo dock version 2.4 without a problem.

Now, after the upgrade via a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 with cairo dock 3.x the system freezes and i have to restart. 
Machine is acer with core i3 2nd generation and 6gb ram.
Is this a known bug ?  Is there a workaround ?

I am a beginner with Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried no OpenGL version?

Comment: thanks. did not try . how do I go about this?
sorry if that is dumb question.

Answer (score 3):

Press Super key (Windows key) or click on the dash button (top most button in unity launcher) and search for "cairo-dock", 
You'll see two Cairo-dock icons, select "Cario-Dock (no OpenGL)"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful help. Its working now with the no open gl option.